# How to stop the audio playing when I navigate to another page in the same file?

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I have a file with a story [Demo story](http://www.centerwow.com/main/portfolio/1/). When I move to the next page, I am using the right arrow key. The old page continues playing while I am in the new page and I need to hear the new record.

1. How can I create an event or make another solution when I go to the next page to stop the old playing?

I am still in the same file when I go to the next page.

```
<footer>
    <div style="position:relative;width:100%;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
    <div style="width:960px;height:94px;position:relative;margin:0px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
        <audio controls="controls">
          <source src="CarlyAndHerLemons1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
          <source src="CarlyAndHerLemons1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
</footer>
```

I think I should use by code similar to `document.getElementById('demo').pause()`

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly post a simplified demo to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), where it's easier for us to tinker with, and adapt, your code? Otherwise we're left trying to make changes using the dev console (or building our own versions of your page) which is possible, it's just far more difficult than it needs to be. Please, help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your audio tag an ID and then use:

```
document.getElementById('yourAudioTagID').pause();
```

Also [this](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/mastering-the-html5-audio-property) page might be useful.

---

Edit:

Here is a [`JSFiddle` Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kamc8/).